# ERROR in Android Studio With Java 8 and Ubuntu 14.10- EGL_EMULATION EGL_INITIALIZATION FAILED

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, android-studio, emulation

i  am running android studio with java 8 and ubuntu 14.10 
Everything is freshly installed and installation worked fine for almost 3 days .
Today i created a new project for experimenting new stuff and ran hello world(didn't edited anything) on emulator to make sure that everything is working fine.Then i got the following error

`02-02 11:59:43.495    3130-3145/app.training.krishna.kittu.androidtraining D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true`

`02-02 11:59:43.499    3130-3130/app.training.krishna.kittu.androidtraining D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6c4f510, tid 3130`

`02-02 11:59:43.499    3130-3130/app.training.krishna.kittu.androidtraining E/﹕ QemuPipeStream::writeFully failed: I/O error`

`02-02 11:59:43.502    3130-3130/app.training.krishna.kittu.androidtraining E/﹕ QemuPipeStream::readFully failed (buf 0xbf98fcac): I/O error`

`02-02 11:59:43.502    3130-3130/app.training.krishna.kittu.androidtraining D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...`

`02-02 11:59:43.804    3130-3145/app.training.krishna.kittu.androidtraining D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6c4f700, tid 3145`

`02-02 11:59:43.804    3130-3145/app.training.krishna.kittu.androidtraining E/﹕ QemuPipeStream::writeFully failed: I/O error`

`02-02 11:59:43.804    3130-3145/app.training.krishna.kittu.androidtraining E/﹕ QemuPipeStream::readFully failed (buf 0xa68389bc): I/O error`

`02-02 11:59:43.804    3130-3145/app.training.krishna.kittu.androidtraining E/﹕ QemuPipeStream::writeFully failed: I/O error`

`02-02 11:59:43.804    3130-3145/app.training.krishna.kittu.androidtraining E/﹕ QemuPipeStream::readFully failed (buf 0xae17d048): I/O error`

`02-02 11:59:43.804    3130-3145/app.training.krishna.kittu.androidtraining E/﹕ QemuPipeStream::readFully failed (buf 0xae17d04c): I/O error`

`02-02 11:59:43.804    3130-3145/app.training.krishna.kittu.androidtraining E/﹕ QemuPipeStream::readFully failed (buf 0xa68389bc): I/O error`

`02-02 11:59:43.804    3130-3145/app.training.krishna.kittu.androidtraining W/libEGL﹕ eglInitialize(0xae17d040) failed (EGL_SUCCESS)`

`02-02 11:59:43.804    3130-3145/app.training.krishna.kittu.androidtraining I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4`

`02-02 11:59:43.804    3130-3145/app.training.krishna.kittu.androidtraining E/EGL_emulation﹕ tid 3145: eglChooseConfig(568): error 0x3001 (EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED)`

`02-02 11:59:43.804    3130-3145/app.training.krishna.kittu.androidtraining W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...`

`02-02 11:59:43.804    3130-3145/app.training.krishna.kittu.androidtraining E/EGL_emulation﹕ tid 3145: eglChooseConfig(568): error 0x3001 (EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED)`

`02-02 11:59:43.804    3130-3145/app.training.krishna.kittu.androidtraining A/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to choose config, error = EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED`

`02-02 11:59:43.804  3130-3145/app.training.krishna.kittu.androidtraining A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2, fault addr 0xb72d737c in tid 3145 (RenderThread)`

Please Guys with experience with these must only answer , and dont ask me to use geny motion i have my own limitations

using api 21 in nexus 4 with x86 image (my system is 32 so please dont ask me to change that )

emulator is working very good no lag 
Solving this will be lot of help to me